# How to add one parameter to every object in array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

so i have some cases.

Add category to every object in array, which holds in state

Posts, are array of object ( these object are wordpress article, and have a lot of parameters)

It's holded in state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      postCategories: [],
    };
  }
```

Later i getting data from other endpoints (category for every posts, from another endpoint)

```
      fetch(postsUrl)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
               posts: data,
            })
            const postcategory = data.map((category) => category.categories)

            if (postcategory === 2)
            {
                console.log("category1" + postcategory)
            }
            if(postcategory === 3){
                console.log("category2" + postcategory)
            }
        })
```

**postcategory** - every category from every posts (But it's enum not string (1,2,3 etc.))

I need to add parameter to every object in array - **posts** depends on e.num
(if posts[0] have postcategory 1 i need to inject parameter name: **category**, with content dependend on enum.

eg. for post[0] it's postcategory = 2 so i need to inject parameter name: category with value "category2"

Additionally, the solution should include all objects in the array - loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and `spread` to achieve this

```
const result = array.map(item =>{
    if(condition1)
        return {...item, newProperty: 'foo'}

    if(condition2)
       return {...item, anotherProp: 'bar'}

    return item
})
```

Comment: Wow thanks, it's adding parameter to every object, now i going to try match this to my problem :)

Comment: Ok, i implement it to my solution and it's generally work, now i trying resolve the issue with conditions

Comment: If you want post another question!

Comment: if(item.categories === 2),                     if(item.categories === 3) These condition didn't add parameter name to every object of array

Comment: The gist is: `map` should always return `item`  that's why I put `return item` at the end, cause if no condition is satisfied `item` isn't modified. If you want to add properties to all items withour restritions just do like: `arr.map(i =>({...i, newProp: 'foo'))`

Comment: Ok, how condition should look if "item.categories" is a string in array? And depends on it's string i need to inject other prop

Comment: Could you post another question explaining better? Comments are just messy!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58438070/how-to-inject-prop-depends-on-condition

Answer (score 1):

To alter the data received from the fetch, you have to change the data inside the map function. The whole array will be returned into `newPostData` which you can then set in state.

```
fetch(postsUrl)
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data => {
  const newPostData = data.map(item => {
    if (item.categories === 2) {
      item.myNewValue = 'the new value if categories is 2';
    }
    if (item.categories === 3)
      console.log('Categories equals 3')

    return item
  }

  this.setState({posts: newPostData})
})
```

Comment: You're mutating the state